# Tailwind CSS WGAG

Tags: accessibility, tailwind-css

Tailwind is good, but how to implement Accessibility mode for disabled users? I mean W3C [WGAG2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/) recommendations.

In common CSS there will be addictional "wgag.css" file which determines site appearance for such situations like: grayscale mode, high contrast, bigger text size, text only and so on.
But how to resolve this with Tailwind CSS? How do you deal with it?

Comment: With a help of [modifiers](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states) - it is up to you how would you implement different features, but general approach in CSS is to use variants (including custom one)

Comment: There seem to be some misunderstandings. You cannot render badly accessible HTML compliant with the WCAG by adding CSS. There also shouldn’t be an accessibility “mode”, sites should be accessible by default, since the whole point of the WCAG is to make sure the site is compatible with a wide range of [assistive technology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assistive_technology) that people with disabilities already use and expect to work. Text should zoom when using _Ctrl+_, for example. WCAG make sure the layout doesn’t break when doing so.

Comment: There are some parts of WCAG, that allow you to offer an additional stylesheet that solves one particular need, for example high contrast, which the user can activate.
What do you mean with “common CSS”, though?

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic silver-bullet that will make your site accessible with Tailwind or any other framework, and it can't be accomplished with CSS alone. You need to implement a combination of accessible HTML, CSS and JavaScript to do the job right.

Accessibility is a discipline unto itself and one worth learning as a developer.

Although Tailwind claims to be accessible, I believe that a major shortcoming of the product is that there's no JS included, which means that you'll have to self-manage things like accessible keyboard navigation, dropdown menus, flyout menus, `aria-expanded` state, closing of modals, pagination, accordions, and anything else that relies on an event listener.

I wouldn't recommend anyone trying to do all of those things on a big complex website unless you really have some years of experience under your belt implementing WCAG and making accessible websites.

Presumably as a response to this limitation, Tailwind is now selling access to "UI components" that have React/Vue JS support. Bootstrap has historically been very good about producing reasonably accessible components with JS built-in.

If you really just have no idea of where to start, try [WebAIM](https://webaim.org/). You can also use automated checking tools like WAVE or LightHouse, but I'd proceed with caution on those. Many less-experienced developers interpret a lack of errors in an automated checker as evidence of an accessible webpage, however that's often not true.